# Using Google place Api, cant get desired result

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

In my `Asp.net` application, I came across a situation where I need to show my clients stores on `Google Map` based on search keyword by user. I did that successfully, but my client now want me to show stores in searched location as well as nearby locations. I found `Google Place API` but it gives other results than my client stores as it can support [these types only.](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) which return unwanted result. I want to show stores that are in my DB. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself :) . as values were coming from database and I was not storing `latlng` and just address. I decided to store `latlng` too with the help of `GoogleMaps.LocationServices.dll` which I downloaded using `Nuget Package Manager`. Now I have  address along with `latlng` in my table, so I used following query to find `latlong` that are within 10 miles from searched `latlong` using following query

```
SELECT
   (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(51.4579242) )
      * cos( radians( lattitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.1660149) )
      + sin ( radians(51.4579242) )
      * sin( radians( lattitude ) )
    )
  ) AS 'distance', lattitude, longitude
FROM stockist
where (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(51.4579242) )
      * cos( radians( lattitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.1660149) )
      + sin ( radians(51.4579242) )
      * sin( radians( lattitude ) )
    )
  )  < 10
```

**Note:**

here 51.4579242 is input `latitude` and  `-0.1660149` is input `longitude`. (Ofcourse  user dont know these technical term so I get post code from user, found all addresses for that code in DB and used `geocoder` for getting `latlong`)
Here, `stickist` is table-name and `lattitude` and `longitude` are columns.
To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

I got all near by `latlong` and plotted them :)